# What is This Moon-Phase Calculation Function Doing?

Tags: c, math

I'm currently reading through the [MEAP](https://www.manning.com/meap-program) book [*Tiny C Projects*](https://www.manning.com/books/tiny-c-projects?query=Tiny) by Dan Gookin. In the opening chapter he presents a small daily greeting program which also reports the phase of the moon. The calculations in the book for this look very strange - he also states outright that he doesn't know where he first got this code from or even what it's doing; it also doesn't have any comments or links to any other explanatory information. This is my cleaned-up rendition of it:

```
int moonphase_from_tm(struct tm* datetime)
{
    int year  = datetime->tm_year;
    int month = datetime->tm_mon;
    int day   = datetime->tm_mday;

    if (month == 2)
    {
        day += 31;
    }
    else if (month > 2)
    {
        day += 59 + (month - 3) * 30.6 + 0.5;
    }

    int g = year % 19;
    int e = (11 * g + 29) % 30;

    if (e == 25 || e == 24)
    {
        ++e;
    }

    int phase = ((((e + day) * 6 + 5) % 177) / 22 & 7);
    
    return phase;
}
```

It returns an `int` used to index a string out of a `char*` array describing the current moon phase.

Can anybody figure out what this is actually doing? I looked up moon phase calculations on Google and can't find anything that bears more than a passing resemblance to this. It also isn't *entirely* accurate with the entire thing being calculated with *int*s (it's out by a day or so, checking against some moon-phase tracking websites), which makes finding something similar a little more difficult.

Below is the original old-style version as reproduced in the book; when calling it, the author adds `1900` to the date, but then this is immediately subtracted again on line 13 when assigning to `g`, so I just didn't bother doing either:

```
int moonphase_book_verbatim(int year, int month, int day)
{
    int d, g, e;

    d = day;
    if (month == 2)
    {
        d += 31;
    }
    else if (month > 2)
    {
        d += 59 + (month - 3) * 30.6 + 0.5;
    }

    g = (year - 1900) % 19;
    e = (11 * g + 29) % 30;

    if (e == 25 || e == 24)
    {
        ++e;
    }

    return ((((e + d) * 6 + 5) % 177) / 22 & 7);
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that this question has not much to do with programming. You might have better luck on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ if you first extract the math from the code, then describe it in clear, human language as well as mathematical formulas in standard notiation.

Comment: It is a great example however, on the absurdity of [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

Comment: BTW if I were a reviewer of that book, I would give the author a hard time over such an "I don't understand this calculation but here it is anyway" example, especially since it's supposed to be an introductory example.

Comment: What is it you don't understand? The C code or what it calculates?

Comment: @Szabolcs Very true - and good suggestion, thank you!
I did wonder if there was some C-specific behaviour involved in it's calculation though, especially looking at the `else if` block where an `int` is multiplied by and added to two `float`s and then put back into an `int`, order of operations, etc...

Comment: I can find some of the constants in other moon-phase calculations. For example 30.6 appears as a constant in this [moon-phase algorithm.](https://www.subsystems.us/uploads/9/8/9/4/98948044/moonphase.pdf). Taking the year mod 19 seems to be a simplification allowed by the [Metonic cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle).

Comment: @4386427 I don't understand how it calculates what it does. The output is just an `int` between 0 - 7 which refers to a moon phase. The actual code is pretty straightforward, save for a few oddities; so, it's the oddities and the calculation itself that I'm lost on.
As @Szabolcs said, post is probably just not the best fit for this board.

Comment: The only C trick is this part: `d += 59 + (month - 3) * 30.6 + 0.5;` The RHS is a floating point calculation but the result is stored in an integer. That has some special implications. The rest is very basic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not about programming

Comment: It looks like a very complicated way of calculating `int moonphase(time_t t) { return lround(8*(t - reference_new_moon_time)/(24*60*60*29.53059))&7; }`.